# Guessing words without the random module? And how do people try again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm making a guessing game where I guess words. Is it possible to make it without the random module? I got to here:

```
print("What`s your name?")
name = input()
print("Hello, %s! this is a guessing game." %name)
print("If you want to start hit ENTER, if not you can exit")

input()

print("Okay, so you want to continue! Nice lets start")
print("What animal lives in Africa and has a long neck")

animal = "giraffe"

while animal != "giraffe":
    print("Wrong answer! Try again.")
```

Basically, I got to an infinitive loop and I don't know how to make people try again.
Also for every person that asked "why don't you want to use the random module", well I'm trying to learn do I learn when I make it easier for myself? I need to solve problems and this is the problem I wanted to solve.

Comment: You have not used an input statement, for the answer.

Comment: If you need something random, then random module is a way to go. Why don't you want to use it? Standard library exists for the sole reason of being available whenever you need it

Comment: Can you please clarify *why* you don't want to use the ``random`` module so that it's clear what else people can/cannot use? For example, is using Unix ``/dev/random`` allowed? Is using a custom PRNG allowed?

Comment: Or for that matter, how randomness is relevant in this case at all? The code has no choice at all, so there is nothing to randomise.

Comment: For the second part see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Comment: What does this have anything to do with the random module to begin with? You haven't gotten anywhere close to needing it yet.

Comment: I checked about what I wanted to do on the internet before creating this post. There I saw people using the random module for problems related to mine. That's why I created this post so I could ask about how do I fix the code to make it work without this module if it were needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
guess = input("What animal lives in Africa and has a long neck?")

while guess!="giraffe":
    guess = input("Wrong answer! Try again:")
```

Answer (score 1):

this could work @Ziolekx ?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3


print("What`s your name?")
name = input()
print("Hello, %s! this is a guessing game." %name)
print("If you want to start hit ENTER, if not you can exit")

input()

print("Okay, so you want to continue! Nice lets start")
print("What animal lives in Africa and has a long neck")

animal = ''

while animal != "giraffe":
    animal = input('Enter your guess: ')
    if(animal == 'giraffe'):
        print('You win!')
    else:
        print("Wrong answer! Try again.")
```

- a nice addition to your script would be to lowercase the input and then compare, in case someone added "Giraffe" for example

Comment: I think you need a `break` after printing a win message?

Comment: Hey @SpoonMeiser a break will not hurt anyone. However the while loop will end since it's condition will not longer be satisfied. Thank you for the input. Feel free to run it, it's a fairly benign script.

Comment: Ahh, yes - I somehow missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

you can take input form the user inside your for loop. And also you are making wrong comparison.

*correct code*:

```py
while name!= animal:
    print("Wrong answer! Try again.")
    name = input('Input Answer again: ')
```

Comment: Why are you comparing the user's *name* with animal? Your comparison is wrong.